# Did a caterpillar or mealybugs cause my olive tree to drop all ti

Tags: leaves, pest-damage

I brought my olive tree inside from the balcony. After 2 weeks leaves started dropping off like crazy. At first I thought it was the shock of moving it, but I found that there was a lot of clumped up spider web like residue on the leaves and they had grown in distorted ways.

Location: London, UK

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

However, I also found this caterpillar inside one of the curled up leaves. Could it have been caterpillars laying eggs and growing in the leaves that caused all the damage? How might it have arrived on my 2nd floor balcony?
[image]

Comment: The web might in fact be from caterpillars, it would be helpful if you could mention the region in the world you live in. You don't need to give your address, don't worry, but country or part of large country would be helpful for proper ID this pest.

Comment: I've added my location (london uk)